# pandas df.apply Including condition with NaN values

Tags: dataframe, logic, nan, outliers, pandas-apply

I'm trying to replace outliers and NaN values in my pandas.DataFrame with the mode of the series, using the apply method and a lambda function and filtering by a property. I've tried in three different ways but it doesn't seems to capture the cases with NaN values.

```
df.apply(   lambda row: mode 
        if (row['prop1']>quart95 or row['prop1']==np.nan) and row['prop2']=='some_value'
        else row['prop1'], axis=1 )

df.apply(   lambda row: mode 
            if (row['prop1']>quart95 or row['prop1']==None) and row['prop2']=='some_value'
            else row['prop1'], axis=1 )

df.apply(   lambda row: mode 
            if (row['prop1']>quart95 or not row['prop1']) and row['prop2']=='some_value'
            else row['prop1'], axis=1 )
```

Why it works finding the outliers but it doesn't with the NaNs ?
How could I fix it or do it?

Comment: I think `np.isnan(value)` is the way to check a value for nan (i.e., don't use `value == np.nan`) Reference: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/dealing-with-missing-values-nan-and-none-in-python-6fc9b8fb4f31 (also deals a bit with the subject of python None values in this article).

Answer (score 0):

supposing `mode` is a single value (not a list):

```
df[df[column_name].isna() | df[column_name]>quart95] = mode
```

You can use the `bitwise OR operator (|)` to do this condition. Plese, refer to [this link](https://realpython.com/python-bitwise-operators/#bitwise-or) to understand more about bitwise operators.